# Unable to load picture or PDF file - Xelatex

Tags: graphics, xetex, compiling

As of recently I am having a problem of compiling my `.tex` file. Mainly it fails when processing or loading an image but only for xelatex, while pdflatex works fine.

Here's the sample code:

```latex
% Setting the page size and font size. %
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

% Package used for image formating.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {"img"} }


\begin {document}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3 \textwidth, keepaspectratio]{"elasticjawcoupling.png"}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output message when compiling with xelatex:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test_latex.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)
(./test_latex.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

LaTeX Warning: File `"elasticjawcoupling.png"' not found on input line 10.

! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'elasticjawcoupling.png'.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.10 ...keepaspectratio]{"elasticjawcoupling.png"}
                                                  
? 

! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.

See the graphics package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 ...keepaspectratio]{"elasticjawcoupling.png"}
                                                  
? 
[1] (./test_latex.aux)
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed. Could not find file: elasticjawcoupling.png

No output PDF file written.
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file test_latex.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on test_latex.log.
```

Here's the output of `xelatex --version`:

```
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 74.2; using 74.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.3.1; using 1.3.1
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.13.2; using 2.13.2
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 8.3.0; using 8.3.1
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.43; using 1.6.43
Compiled with pplib version v2.2
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.15.0; using 2.15.0
```

The "compiler" should properly process these files. Since it can be loaded with pdflatex that would mean that the problem lies within xelatex. Pdflatex was just used to see if it will even compile the document.

Comment: try without the quotes around the filename and the img in the graphic path.

Comment: also it should be `{img/}` with a `/`

Answer (score 1):

After trying what @David Carlisle and @Ulrike Fischer have suggested i've managed to compile it and it works fine.

I guess this was not the source of the problem but it was a fix for it since before it has worked fine.

EDIT:

```latex
% Setting the page size and font size. %
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

% Package used for image formating.
\usepackage{graphicx}
% quotes removed with a forward slash
\graphicspath{ {img/} }


\begin {document}

% quotes removed
\includegraphics[width=0.3 \textwidth, keepaspectratio]{elasticjawcoupling.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX changed the quote handling (to better support file names with spaces), and now you really shouldn't use quotes anymore.

Comment: It's generally better to ask somebody who commented to write an answer, but I suspect David and Ulrike will weather the loss of reputation ;). Could you put the actual solution in your answer, though? Comments are ephemeral and liable to get deleted. If anybody has the same question, they will look for the solution in an answer.